# Find an example of non abelian group which satisfies certain properties.

Tags: group-theory

Show that there is a group $G$ and consecutive numbers $i, i + 1$ such that $G$ is not abelian but does have the property that $(ab)^i = a^ib^i$ and $(ab)^{i+1} = a^{i+1}b^{i+1}$ for all $a,b \in G$.

I have already proved that ---

$G$ is abelian if and only if $(ab)^{i+2} = a^{i+2}b^{i+2}$.

But I could not find an example of a non-abelian group that shows the above. I was thinking of matrix groups but could not find any such example.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A more challenging exercise would be to prove that there exists such a $G$ for all $i \ge 3$. (The condition for $i=2$ clearly implies that $G$ is abelian.)

Comment: @DerekHolt Can't we just take $G$ to be a non-abelian group of exponent $i$?

Comment: @James Yes, and that's easier than I thought at first because you can take that to be a direct product $H \times C_n$, where $H$ is nonabelian of exponent either $4$ or an odd prime dividing $i$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** Try the smallest non-abelian group, and take $i=6$.